# Typescript: Optional Parameter in function, depending on Union Type has property

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a union type:

```
type Msg = { type: 'banana', value: number[] } | { type: 'apple' };
```

now i would like to create a function that creates such a Fruit type, with two arguments and takes a generic for the `Msg`:

```
const createMsg = <M extends { type: string }>(type: M["type"], value?: M["value"]) => ({ type, value });
```

The `value` argument of the function should be linked to the type of `value` of the union type, and if it's not defined, the param should be optional. I would like to be able to call it in two ways:

```
createMsg('banana', [1, 2, 3]);
createMsg('apple');
```

All my current solutions so far forced me to provide a second argument `undefined` for the `'apple'` union-type.

Comment: Overloads perhaps could be of use here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have conditional parameters, the most simple way to do this is to pass a `Msg` to `createMsg`:

```js
const createMsg = (msg: Msg): Msg => (msg)

const a = createMsg({ type: "apple" })
const b = createMsg({ type: "banana", value: [1,2,3] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use overloads (although this can get finicky with many more constituents):

```
type Type = { type: "foo"; value: number[] } | { type: "bar" };

function createMessage(type: "foo", value: number[]): Type;
function createMessage(type: "bar"): Type;
function createMessage(type: "foo" | "bar", value?: number[]) {
    if (value) return { type, value };
    
    return { type };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8qkgLigIgGYHt9sBuKANwEMAbAVwiwDsaBbAIwgCcBtAXSgF8oAHxRp4WbKwodsA4gCh5uGgwDGwAJb4GUVRwgVgEALIQAzmYoBzCAAp09HASIAactTqMW7bjwCUWHCQCspqmtq6+oYm5pY29uI4UjIBsPAhKupaOnoGRqYW1nYOEs6yIpLS2G6UtBAA-F5snLx+KPJQnVAauFC2tXRt+sA0HDqoDjUe0PwKHV3Do+NikHLy-Iq50QVxdniE1VCtClv5sUW2lSlzpzGF8ftEfidRZ-d7yYfHQA)